# How to display correct value? discord.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a currency system with mySQL. So, the problem I'm encountering is when a user types ?add (add currency )and then ?bal (to get user's balance) everything is fine, but if a user after them types ?bal, the bot will show the previous user's balance:

Expected output

```
User1: ?add

Bot: Now you have 10 money!

User1: ?bal

Bot: You have 10 money!

User2: ?bal

Bot: You have 20 money!
```

Actual output

```
User1: ?add

Bot: Now you have 10 money!

User1: ?bal

Bot: You have 10 money!

User2: ?bal

Bot: You have 10 money! //which is User1's bal
```

And the weird thing is that in the database the values are fine (example: User1 - 10; User2 - 20)
Below is the code

```
if(command == "add"){
      con.query(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

       

        if(rows.length < 1){
       sql = `INSERT INTO money (id, money) VALUES ('${msg.author.id}', '${add}')`
        }else{
         
          let money = rows[0].money;
          sql = `UPDATE money SET money = ${money + add} WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}' `
          msg.channel.send(`Now you have ${money} money!`)
        
        }
        con.query(sql, console.log)
        
      })
      
    }
      if(command == "bal"){
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}'`, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          msg.channel.send(`You have ${money} money!`)

      })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the connection before you start another one, otherwise it just queries the same thing.

```js
if(command == "add") {
  con.start() // I am not sure of the syntax for starting a connection, but this is an assumption
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(rows.length < 1) {
   sql = `INSERT INTO money (id, money) VALUES ('${msg.author.id}', '${add}')`
    }else{
     
      let money = rows[0].money;
      sql = `UPDATE money SET money = ${money + add} WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}' `
      msg.channel.send(`Now you have ${money} money!`)
    
    }
    con.query(sql, console.log)
    con.end(); // these are important, because they close the connection
  })
}

if(command == "bal") {
    con.start() 
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM money WHERE id = '${msg.author.id}'`, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      msg.channel.send(`You have ${money} money!`)
    con.end();
  })
}
```

I am unsure of the nature of the syntax for starting a query, but I found online that `<connection>.end()` is used

I have never used MySQL and personally use `better-sqlite3` since it is 40x faster, but this is what I think you are doing wrong.